# same train and eval dataset but get a different result

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

#### Versions:

- TensorFlow: 1.8.0
- TensorBoard: 1.8.0

#### What i did:

I'm training a model with imbalanced dataset with [tf.estimator.DNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier). When i did two times of training process both start from a totally new beginning(AKA, no checkpoint for each training) with the **same data**. I got two results which are very different from each other as shown in the following pictures.
[1st-train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdUMj.jpg)
[2nd-train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gveB0.jpg)

A few points to comment:

- There is not difference between the two training process (no code or data changes), they both start from a new beginning.
- The training dataset size is about 100M.
- Both training results are from 6 epochs. (And each result cost $25 on google ml-engine.)

#### From the two pictures we can tell:

- The 1st training learns nothing for 6 epochs.
- The 2nd training learns (it got a AUC over 0.6).
- Although the difference of AUC values between two trainings is only 0.1 (0.6 - 0.5), but it has big different in the meaning (**a-random-guess** versus **a-non-random-guess**).

#### Problems:

1. Why is this happen: same training data but get a totally different result?

Comment: Certainly not impossible because of the random weight initialization. Not enough information to know why. Sounds like one time didn't really work for some reason. I'd guess the learning rate is too high and you got lucky once.